# Xpath or css selector - scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Am trying to select a "next" navigation link and cannot seem to find the right combination selector in scrapy.

This is the web url:
[search page on boat listing site](https://www.yachtworld.com/boats-for-sale/condition-used/type-power/class-power-sport-fishing/?year=2006-2014&length=40-65)

the link I'm trying to select is this tag:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="icon-chevron-right " href="/boats-for-sale/condition-used/type-power/class-power-sport-fishing/?year=2006-2014&amp;length=40-65&amp;page=2"><span class="aria-fixes">2</span></a>
```

I've tried many combinations of response.xpath and response.css selectors but can't seem to find the right combination.

Using google chrome inspector, I get this xpath:
//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/a[9]

Ultimately, I'm trying to get the href attribute of the tag which contains the URL I want to follow.

Am I running into problems with the rel='nofollow' attribute and a scrapy setting?

EDIT - this code used to work but now get an error on the css selector:

```
def parse(self, response):

        listing_objs =  response.xpath("//div[@class = 'listings-container']/a")
        for listing in listing_objs:

            yield response.follow(listing.attrib['href'], callback= self.parse_detail)

        next_page = response.css("a.icon-chevron-right").attrib['href']

        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can access any page of the website bye adding `&page=#` at the end of URL, this approach will satisfy accessing next page content after current page have been crawled.
For instance you can do something like this:

```
def start_request(self):
    main_url = "https://www.yachtworld.com/boats-for-sale/condition-used/type-power" \
        "/class-power-sport-fishing/?year=2006-2014&length=40-65&page=%(page)s"
    for i in range(pages):
        yield scrapy.Request(main_url % {'page': i}, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Its not clear to me how to determine the number of pages in order to setup the range(pages).  so, am adding what previously worked but it doesn't anymore.   Am thinking scrapy has added a nofollow switch?

Comment: I was able to parse the text that shows items 1-15 of x to determine page length and then use that to paginate the query.    Its kind of clunky using modulo and // operators but it works!    Thanks for your help.  I'm marking this as the right answer altough I wish I could get @CA_Hanson solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

@Piron's answer above is probably the easiest way to iterate over pages, but should you still want to go the Xpath route:

```
response.xpath(".//div[@class='search-page-nav']/a[@class='icon-chevron-right']/@href/text()")
```

Where **search-page-nav** is the parent div class of the other page links, **icon-chevron-right** is the particular class of the a tag you're looking for, **@href** selects the link of that a tag, and **text()** converts the attribute to text.

Comment: i just loaded up scrapy shell "link above" and then executed this.   I got an empty list.